# Interface segregation principle - Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style

I have an interface

```
interface XXXCommandHandler(){
    void parse(String something);
    String response();
    String additionalResponse();
}
```

1. Some of the classes that implement XXXCommandHandler do not implement additionalResponse().
2. I am using ApplicationContextManager.getInstance().getBeansOfType(XXXCommandHandler.class) to get the classes that implement XXXCommandHandler
3. Then call parse, response and additionalResponse
4. Since some do not implement additionalResponse I am forced to return null.

**I can think of the following**

1. Instead of returning null on classes that do not implement additionalResponse, declaire additionalResponse as default method and return null / or make it return Optional etc and override it on the classes that implement additionalResponse method.
2. Ugly way :- return null in all the classes that do not implement additionalResponse
3. Create two different interfaces XXXCommandHandlerParser() with parse and response method and XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse() with additionalResponse method extending XXXCommandHandlerParser i.e

   interface XXXCommandHandlerParser(){

   ```
       void parse(String something);
       String response();

   }
   ```

   interface XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse() 
   extends XXXCommandHandlerParser {

   ```
       String additionalResponse();
   }
   ```
4. But if I do #3 I had to change 
   ApplicationContextManager.getInstance().getBeansOfType(XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse.class).
5. If I do #4 then classes that do not implement additionalResponse or that do not implement XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse will not be picked up.

Can you think of any elegant way?

Comment: @Mena - I think u mean #1 Optional in interface default method.

Comment: "I have an interface `interface XXXCommandHandler(){...`"... that's not valid Java.

Comment: Hari, still you need to format the code properly for better readability

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of taste which solution is more elegant but there is (at least) one more way to go:

1. Create a top level interface: interfaceA
2. Extend interfaceA to interfaceB with the extra method.
3. Collect beans of type interfaceA
4. If the instance is interfaceB than cast and call the extra method.

Maybe it is no more elegant than having a default implementation returning an optional.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what "additionalResponse" is, it might be ok to declare it in the base interface, add an implementation returning null (or an empty String?) to a base implementation and add the real implementations to the respective subclasses.

In real world problems, it usually helps to think about whether another developer might be surprised by the implementation you plan and might therefor use it in a way that leads to bugs.

If you want to go fancy, the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) might be a candidate.

While subclassing is usually frowned upon by the pattern gurus as it is used more often than justified, it's something people know and expect. That would be the solution @Zsolt V recommends (here as pseudo-code - might not compile):

```
Collection<XXXCommandHandler> baseHandlers = ApplicationContextManager.getInstance()
  .getBeansOfType(XXXCommandHandler.class).values();
for (XXXCommandHandler baseHandler: basehHandlers) {
  baseHandler.parse(something);
  baseHandler.response();

  if (baseHandler instanceof XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse.class) {
    XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse additionalResponseHandler
      = (XXXCommandHandlerAddtionalresponse) baseHandler:
    additionalResponseHandler.additionalResponse();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will also try to help you. From my point of view you can create an interface or direct class Response and return it instead of String. And there you can add method supportsAdditionalResponse and check it before getting additionalResponse. And in if additionalResponse is not supported then throw in getAdditionalResponse method UnsupportedOperationException.

From my point of view ApplicationContextManager.getInstance().getBeansOfType(XXXCommandHandler.class) is also not a good thing cause you are exposing your infrastructure. Better way will be to add method List getCommandHandlers() if it is possible.

```
   public interface Response {
     String getResponse();

     default Boolean supportsAdditionalResponse() {
       return false;
     };

     default String getAdditionalResponse() {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
     }
   }


   public class HttpResponse implements Response {
    private String response;

     public HttpResponse(String response) {
      this.response = response;
     }

    @Override
    public String getResponse() {
      return response;
    }

  }

  public interface CommandHandler {
    void parse(String command);
    Response getResponse();
  }

  public class HttpCommandHandler implements CommandHandler {
    private final Response response;

    public HttpCommandHandler(Response response) {
     this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public void parse(String command) {
     //do smth
    }

    @Override
    public Response getResponse() {
      return response;
    }
 }
```